# trying out derby and following instructions produces java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError error

Tags: java, jdbc, hive, derby

I am following the derby tutorial from:

```
http://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/
```

I successfully installed the derby on the system:

```
hduser@libafd:/usr/local/derby$ java org.apache.derby.tools.sysinfo
------------------ Java Information ------------------
Java Version:    1.7.0_79
Java Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
Java home:       /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
Java classpath:  /usr/local/derby/lib/derby.jar:/usr/local/derby/lib/derbytools.jar::/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-cli-1.2.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/velocity-1.5.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/calcite-core-1.2.0-incubating.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/geronimo-annotation_1.0_spec-1.1.1.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/guava-14.0.1.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/calcite-avatica-1.2.0-incubating.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/jdo-api-3.0.1.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/maven-scm-provider-svn-commons-1.4.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/stax-api-1.0.1.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/asm-tree-3.1.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/curator-recipes-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/libfb303-0.9.2.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/janino-2.7.6.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/commons-vfs2-2.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/commons-pool-1.5.4.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/libthrift-0.9.2.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/super-csv-2.2.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-jdbc-1.2.0-standalone.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/accumulo-core-1.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-common-1.2.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/pentaho-aggdesigner-algorithm-5.1.5-jhyde.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/accumulo-trace-1.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/junit-4.11.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-serde-1.2.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/curator-client-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/jcommander-1.32.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/geronimo-jaspic_1.0_spec-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-shims-0.20S-1.2.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/bonecp-0.8.0.RELEASE.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/mail-1.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-beeline-1.2.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/netty-3.7.0.Final.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/jpam-1.1.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/httpcore-4.4.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-metastore-1.2.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/commons-httpclient-3.0.1.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/ant-1.9.1.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-shims-scheduler-1.2.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/commons-compiler-2.7.6.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-exec-1.2.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/jsr305-3.0.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/json-20090211.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/accumulo-start-1.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/activation-1.1.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/oro-2.0.8.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-ant-1.2.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-testutils-1.2.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/calcite-linq4j-1.2.0-incubating.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/jetty-all-server-7.6.0.v20120127.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/ST4-4.0.4.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/commons-math-2.1.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/ivy-2.4.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/ant-launcher-1.9.1.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-service-1.2.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/maven-scm-api-1.4.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/opencsv-2.3.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/jetty-all-7.6.0.v20120127.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/eigenbase-properties-1.1.5.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/snappy-java-1.0.5.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/curator-framework-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/maven-scm-provider-svnexe-1.4.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/apache-log4j-extras-1.2.17.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/stringtemplate-3.2.1.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/plexus-utils-1.5.6.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/accumulo-fate-1.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/groovy-all-2.1.6.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/tempus-fugit-1.1.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-hwi-1.2.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/derby-10.11.1.1.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-jdbc-1.2.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/antlr-2.7.7.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/httpclient-4.4.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/jta-1.1.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/jline-2.12.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/parquet-hadoop-bundle-1.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-shims-0.23-1.2.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-contrib-1.2.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-accumulo-handler-1.2.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/regexp-1.3.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/joda-time-2.5.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/antlr-runtime-3.4.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-shims-1.2.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/avro-1.7.5.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/asm-commons-3.1.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-shims-common-1.2.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/hamcrest-core-1.1.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-hbase-handler-1.2.0.jar:.:/usr/local/derby/lib/derby.jar:/usr/local/derby/lib/derbytools.jar
OS name:         Linux
OS architecture: amd64
OS version:      3.5.0-52-generic
Java user name:  hduser
Java user home:  /home/hduser
Java user dir:   /usr/local/db-derby-10.4.2.0-bin
java.specification.name: Java Platform API Specification
java.specification.version: 1.7
--------- Derby Information --------
JRE - JDBC: Java SE 6 - JDBC 4.0
[/usr/local/db-derby-10.4.2.0-bin/lib/derby.jar] 10.4.2.0 - (689064)
[/usr/local/db-derby-10.4.2.0-bin/lib/derbytools.jar] 10.4.2.0 - (689064)
[/usr/local/apache-hive-1.2.0-bin/lib/hive-jdbc-1.2.0-standalone.jar] 10.11.1.1 - (1616546)
[/usr/local/apache-hive-1.2.0-bin/lib/derby-10.11.1.1.jar] 10.11.1.1 - (1616546)
------------------------------------------------------
----------------- Locale Information -----------------
Current Locale :  [English/United States [en_US]]
Found support for locale: [cs]
     version: 10.4.2.0 - (689064)
Found support for locale: [de_DE]
     version: 10.4.2.0 - (689064)
Found support for locale: [es]
     version: 10.4.2.0 - (689064)
Found support for locale: [fr]
     version: 10.4.2.0 - (689064)
Found support for locale: [hu]
     version: 10.4.2.0 - (689064)
Found support for locale: [it]
     version: 10.4.2.0 - (689064)
Found support for locale: [ja_JP]
     version: 10.4.2.0 - (689064)
Found support for locale: [ko_KR]
     version: 10.4.2.0 - (689064)
Found support for locale: [pl]
     version: 10.4.2.0 - (689064)
Found support for locale: [pt_BR]
     version: 10.4.2.0 - (689064)
Found support for locale: [ru]
     version: 10.4.2.0 - (689064)
Found support for locale: [zh_CN]
     version: 10.4.2.0 - (689064)
Found support for locale: [zh_TW]
     version: 10.4.2.0 - (689064)
------------------------------------------------------
hduser@libafd:/usr/local/derby$
```

when I continue with the ij Basics chapter from the tutorial I get the following error:

```
hduser@libafd:/usr/local/derby$ java org.apache.derby.tools.ij
ij version 10.4
ij> connect 'jdbc:derby:MyDbTest;create=true';
JAVA ERROR: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
ij>
```

or

```
hduser@libafd:/usr/local/derby/lib$ java -Djdbc.drivers=org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver  org.apache.derby.tools.ij
ij version 10.4
ij> connect 'jdbc:derby:MyDbTest;create=true';
JAVA ERROR: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
ij>
```

How can I fix it (i.e., create a database and continue with the tutorial :) )

Comment: Derby 10.4 is very old; I'm not sure it is compatible with Java 7. Why not try a newer version of Derby? For more information about the error, look in your 'derby.log' file.

Comment: Nice! Thanks, aparently the tutorial is quite old :) I'll give a try and let know whether that worked :)

Comment: A significantly more modern tutorial is here: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/getstart/

Comment: excellent point! updating the derby solved the issue! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that the problem is that you have multiple copies of the Derby JAR in your classpath.  There are three copies of `derby.jar` and two of `derbytools.jar`.

[This page](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/36828-embedded-derby-initialization-problem) shows a similar error to yours, ultimately caused by the exception `java.lang.SecurityException: sealing violation: package org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data is sealed`.  Sealing a package within a JAR prevents classes within this package from being loaded by another JAR, and if you have multiple copies of the Derby JAR on your classpath (especially if the Derby versions are different) then it is quite possible that you will hit a sealing issue like this.

I can run the Derby `ij` tool quite happily with just `derby.jar` and `derby-tools.jar` on the classpath.

Answer (score 1):

Upadating the derby to the newest version solved the issue:

```
hduser@libafd:~$ sysinfo
------------------ Java Information ------------------
Java Version:    1.7.0_79
Java Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
Java home:       /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
Java classpath:  /usr/local/derby/lib/derby.jar:/usr/local/derby/lib/derbynet.jar:/usr/local/derby/lib/derbytools.jar:/usr/local/derby/lib/derbyclient.jar::/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-cli-1.2.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/velocity-1.5.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/calcite-core-1.2.0-incubating.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/geronimo-annotation_1.0_spec-1.1.1.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/guava-14.0.1.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/calcite-avatica-1.2.0-incubating.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/jdo-api-3.0.1.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/maven-scm-provider-svn-commons-1.4.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/stax-api-1.0.1.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/asm-tree-3.1.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/curator-recipes-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/libfb303-0.9.2.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/janino-2.7.6.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/commons-vfs2-2.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/commons-pool-1.5.4.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/libthrift-0.9.2.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/super-csv-2.2.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-jdbc-1.2.0-standalone.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/accumulo-core-1.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-common-1.2.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/pentaho-aggdesigner-algorithm-5.1.5-jhyde.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/accumulo-trace-1.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/junit-4.11.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-serde-1.2.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/curator-client-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/jcommander-1.32.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/geronimo-jaspic_1.0_spec-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-shims-0.20S-1.2.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/bonecp-0.8.0.RELEASE.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/mail-1.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-beeline-1.2.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/netty-3.7.0.Final.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/jpam-1.1.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/httpcore-4.4.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-metastore-1.2.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/commons-httpclient-3.0.1.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/ant-1.9.1.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-shims-scheduler-1.2.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/commons-compiler-2.7.6.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-exec-1.2.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/jsr305-3.0.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/json-20090211.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/accumulo-start-1.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/activation-1.1.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/oro-2.0.8.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-ant-1.2.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-testutils-1.2.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/calcite-linq4j-1.2.0-incubating.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/jetty-all-server-7.6.0.v20120127.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/ST4-4.0.4.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/commons-math-2.1.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/ivy-2.4.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/ant-launcher-1.9.1.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-service-1.2.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/maven-scm-api-1.4.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/opencsv-2.3.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/jetty-all-7.6.0.v20120127.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/eigenbase-properties-1.1.5.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/snappy-java-1.0.5.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/curator-framework-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/maven-scm-provider-svnexe-1.4.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/apache-log4j-extras-1.2.17.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/stringtemplate-3.2.1.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/plexus-utils-1.5.6.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/accumulo-fate-1.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/groovy-all-2.1.6.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/tempus-fugit-1.1.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-hwi-1.2.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/derby-10.11.1.1.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-jdbc-1.2.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/antlr-2.7.7.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/httpclient-4.4.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/jta-1.1.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/jline-2.12.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/parquet-hadoop-bundle-1.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-shims-0.23-1.2.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-contrib-1.2.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-accumulo-handler-1.2.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/regexp-1.3.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/joda-time-2.5.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/antlr-runtime-3.4.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-shims-1.2.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/avro-1.7.5.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/asm-commons-3.1.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-shims-common-1.2.0.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/hamcrest-core-1.1.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-hbase-handler-1.2.0.jar:.:/usr/local/derby/lib/derby.jar:/usr/local/derby/lib/derbytools.jar
OS name:         Linux
OS architecture: amd64
OS version:      3.5.0-52-generic
Java user name:  hduser
Java user home:  /home/hduser
Java user dir:   /home/hduser
java.specification.name: Java Platform API Specification
java.specification.version: 1.7
java.runtime.version: 1.7.0_79-b14
--------- Derby Information --------
[/usr/local/db-derby-10.11.1.1-bin/lib/derby.jar] 10.11.1.1 - (1616546)
[/usr/local/db-derby-10.11.1.1-bin/lib/derbytools.jar] 10.11.1.1 - (1616546)
[/usr/local/db-derby-10.11.1.1-bin/lib/derbynet.jar] 10.11.1.1 - (1616546)
[/usr/local/db-derby-10.11.1.1-bin/lib/derbyclient.jar] 10.11.1.1 - (1616546)
[/usr/local/apache-hive-1.2.0-bin/lib/hive-jdbc-1.2.0-standalone.jar] 10.11.1.1 - (1616546)
[/usr/local/apache-hive-1.2.0-bin/lib/derby-10.11.1.1.jar] 10.11.1.1 - (1616546)
------------------------------------------------------
----------------- Locale Information -----------------
Current Locale :  [English/United States [en_US]]
Found support for locale: [cs]
     version: 10.11.1.1 - (1616546)
Found support for locale: [de_DE]
     version: 10.11.1.1 - (1616546)
Found support for locale: [es]
     version: 10.11.1.1 - (1616546)
Found support for locale: [fr]
     version: 10.11.1.1 - (1616546)
Found support for locale: [hu]
     version: 10.11.1.1 - (1616546)
Found support for locale: [it]
     version: 10.11.1.1 - (1616546)
Found support for locale: [ja_JP]
     version: 10.11.1.1 - (1616546)
Found support for locale: [ko_KR]
     version: 10.11.1.1 - (1616546)
Found support for locale: [pl]
     version: 10.11.1.1 - (1616546)
Found support for locale: [pt_BR]
     version: 10.11.1.1 - (1616546)
Found support for locale: [ru]
     version: 10.11.1.1 - (1616546)
Found support for locale: [zh_CN]
     version: 10.11.1.1 - (1616546)
Found support for locale: [zh_TW]
     version: 10.11.1.1 - (1616546)
------------------------------------------------------
hduser@libafd:~$ java -jar $DERBY_HOME/lib/derbyrun.jar ij
ij version 10.11
ij> CONNECT 'jdbc:derby:firstdb;create=true'
> ;
ij>
```